# Append Textarea result from another class

Tags: java, swing

I have two classes class `Game`  and class `wampusGUI`. In `wampusGUI` class I have one `textarea` named `displayTextArea` under the method `textarea1()`.
I am trying to `append` result to `textarea` from `Game` class. but when I am trying to access from that class . the `function` running fine and also the result is coming in that class (I just tested by simply `System.out.print()`  method), but it is not appending to `textarea`. Here is my code.

```
// Code of wampusGUI  class
public class wampusGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form wampusGUI
     */
    public wampusGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void textArea1(String text) {
        System.out.print(text);
        displayTextArea.append(text); // this is not appending to textarea.
    }

           /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new wampusGUI().setVisible(true);
                   Game g = new Game();
                   g.testing();
            }
        });
    }
```

//Here is the code of Game class

```
      private wampusGUI gui;

      public void testing () {         
          String welCome=welcome();
          gui= new wampusGUI();
          gui.textArea1(welCome);            
     }
```

Comment: It just a simple string here it is - `public String welcome() {
 return "Welcome to my world\n";`
                    }

Comment: or [public lullaby "Welcome to my world\n"](http://www.lyricstime.com/delegation-welcome-to-my-world-lyrics.html) :-)

Comment: where you have defined `displayTextArea`?

Comment: in Gui file. i created using the Java form.  `Private javax.swing.JTextArea displayTextArea;`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make this Changes in your code

In Your First Class wampusGUI

```
public class wampusGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form wampusGUI
     */
    public wampusGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void textArea1(String text) {
        System.out.print(text);
        displayTextArea.append(text); // this is not appending to textarea.
    }

           /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                wampusGUI w=new wampusGUI();
                w.setVisible(true);
                Game g = new Game(w);
                g.testing();
            }
        });
    }
```

And for Second class Game

```
private wampusGUI gui;

//Add Contructor with Parameter

     public Game(wampusGUI w){
      //put this line of code at the end  
      gui=w;
     }

      public void testing () {         
          String welCome=welcome();          
          gui.textArea1(welCome);            
     }
```

this will work...

Answer (score 4):

To append the text in `TextArea`

```
String str = textarea.getText();
str+="appending text";
textarea.setText(str);
```

It may help you.

Comment: no error. program is running but text is not appending to textarea. however, result is coming by simply printing

Comment: this is actually whole code. i have tried that code into another 2 classes just for testing. once i success to fix there i will put into original code

Answer (score 2):

You are creating one instance of wampusGUI inside `run()` of invokeLater, and one instance of wampusGUI inside `testing()` method.

What you are actually doing is appending the text to an textarea you can't see (probably) because you have the other one instance of wampusGUI set visible.