# Swing creating two frames when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two classes one extends `JFrame` which is a swing class and another is normal class. Now I will call the normal class by clicking `JButton` in which I want to embed the values from the normal class into swing class `JTextArea`.

[Based on this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386224/append-textarea-result-from-another-class)

But When I click the button Another frame is created. I know I am calling the swing class's constructor twice. But I don't know how to overcome this problem.

I will call the Swing frame from the main method inside the swing class. But when I click the button I m creating another frame since I call the constructor again. How to overcome this issue?

### SwingClass

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      
        
        Grid grids=new Grid();
        grids.setVisible(true); // based on the above solution
        
        int user=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        if(jTextField1.getText().equals(null))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Please Enter the users");
        }
        else
        {
        GridSourceClass.caller("Grid Class Called",grids,user);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm assuming the `Grid` is you `JFrame` class....